# SOAPUI - How could I use relative path in the Schema compliance assertion?

Tags: soapui, web-api-testing

I created a lot of Schema compliance assertions and set one wadl file for all of them.
I put it in GIT and my teammate take it.

He has problem because at his PC he has another path to the repository directory.

How could I set a unique path to the project directory?

That was I tried without success:

1. Set Project property with path 
   `wadlSource = 'D:\repo\soapui\API.wadl'`
   and then set to the Configure Schema Compliance Assertion path = `'${#Project#wadlSource}'`
2. Set to the Project parameter Resource Root = `'${projectDir}'`
   Set to the Configure Schema Compliance Assertion path = `'\API.wadl'`
3. Set to the Configure Schema Compliance Assertion path = `'${projectDir}\API.wadl'`

These variants don't work, could anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that *Schema compliance* assertion doesn't support property expansion. I create a `wadlSource` property in the *Project* level and then I put as a path `${#Project#wadlSource}` for the *Schema compliance* assertion, but looking in the SOAPUI log you can see:

```
10:39:13,993 ERROR [SoapUI] An error occurred [com.eviware.soapui.impl.support.definition.support.InvalidDefinitionEx
ception], see error log for details
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Programari\SoapUI-5.0.0\bin\${#Project#wadlSource} (The system cannot find the file specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
```

You can try to open a feature-request with SOAPUI.

Anyway to bypass this there are a few options, a possible **workaround** could be to serve the `wadl` file as static content from your own WS (this is the most common way to do so) and configure the *Schema compliance* assertion to this URL.

If this is not an option you can put in some internal *http server* like for example *apache-httpd* where you and your teammate have access an configure the *Schema compliance* assertion to this URL.

**UPDATE:**

I also try with *SOAPUI* version **5.1.2** and the same error happens, seems that property expansion doesn't work in *Schema compilance* assertion url also for this version.

Comment: Thank you for advice. I have asked the same question on SOAP UI community, maybe they can suggest how to use variables or relative path.

Comment: @Vladimir due to the evidences use variable with property expansion at least right now it's not possible... maybe with a newer version or with a feature request.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working around this by serving up the schema files using WireMock, which we were using anyway. You could probably also create a Virtual Service (mock) within SoapUI itself, and start that up to serve the schema files.